# Qt5 on Wayland - how to set keyboard repeat rate?

Tags: qt, wayland, swaywm, qt5

I'm running SwayWM. I set the keyboard repeat delay and rate in `~/.config/sway/config` as:

```
input * repeat_delay 180
input * repeat_rate 50
```

This works in everything except Qt5 applications. Qt5 applications use their own repeat delay and rate, and it is unaffected by the Sway settings.

How can I change the keyboard repeat delay and rate for Qt5 applications running under Wayland?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** 2021-01-23: For some reason it works now. The [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85553) is not marked as fixed and [the code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/platformsupport/input/libinput/qlibinputkeyboard.cpp?h=dev) hasn't changed, so I don't know what the difference is. But the key repeat is fast now.

---

I found the source of the problem.

Qt5 is likely using `libinput` by default on Wayland (I have not confirmed this, but it seems likely). The source for [`qlibinputkeyboard.cpp`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/platformsupport/input/libinput/qlibinputkeyboard.cpp?h=dev) contains hard-coded repeat settings:

```
const int REPEAT_DELAY = 500;
const int REPEAT_RATE = 100;

// ...

m_repeatTimer.setInterval(REPEAT_DELAY);
m_repeatTimer.start();
```

Yup, Qt5 with libinput implements its own repeat using its own hard-coded settings.

So, it seems that, to avoid this, it is necessary to either:

1. Configure Qt5 to use something other than libinput (not sure how to do this); or
2. Fix `qlibinputkeyboard.cpp`.